# Redirect a page in htsccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

m.sample.com/?articulo=**something**

to

http://www.sample.com/camisetas/**something**.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.sample.com$
RewriteRule ^\?articulo=(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/camisetas/$1.html [R=301]
```

Comment: When you say it is not working, you want to say that an errors is displayed or it happens nothing ?

Comment: It's goes to m.sample.com